# What language mechanisms does Lilypond have for simple abbreviations, to avoid code duplication?

Tags: dry, code-duplication, lilypond

In [lilypond](/questions/tagged/lilypond), I often find myself writing things like this

```
\version "2.14.2"
{
  r2 c2 | gis'8 gis gis gis gis gis gis gis |
}
```

or this

```
\version "2.14.2"
{
  \time 3/4 \clef bass \relative es,
  {
    <es \parenthesize es'>8\staccato g bes
    <es, \parenthesize es'>8\staccato g c
  }
}
```

where I repeatedly double some note one octave higher, parenthesized.

I have scoured the [Lilypond documentation](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/), but have not found easy mechanisms to avoid this duplication.  A more complex way is apparently to write a [music function](http://lilypond.org/doc/stable/Documentation/notation/using-music-functions), but that seems to require stepping out into Scheme.

The only mechanism I have found to date is one for which I don't understand the mechanism:

```
\version "2.14.2"
S = #staccato
P = #parenthesize
{
  \time 3/4 \clef bass \relative es,
  {
    <es \P es'>8\S g bes <es, \P es'>8\S g c
  }
}
```

So: How can I write my own slightly more complex abbreviations in Lilypond, without escaping to Scheme?

**Update.** I edited back part of my question, to indicate that (1) I'm currently using 2.14.2, which is current on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS; (2) in my second example, after the `bes` I want to go back to the *previous* `es`, not one octave higher: and since I'm always working in `\relative` mode I intentionally wrote `es,`; (3) I'm looking for a way to abbreviate things like '*this* note with the same one an octave higher, parenthesised'.

Comment: When writing a small LilyPond example, please always add your LilyPond version on the top of the code as `\version "2.17.28"`, since it will help people debug your problem. Also, always add a functional code, so that people can just copy and paste it to see what is going on (both your codes have missing a `{` in the beginning and a `}` in the end, and the first code has a spell mistake; you wrote `gis8'` instead of `gis'8`).

Comment: @gilberto.agostinho.f Sound advice, will do in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it seems you have two questions here. For the first one, simply use the command `\repeat unfold N { ...music... }`, which is described in the documentation on this [link](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.17/Documentation/notation/long-repeats#written_002dout-repeats). So your code above would become something like:

```
\version "2.17.28"
{
  c2 \repeat unfold 8 {gis'8} r2
  es1 | \repeat unfold 2{<es \parenthesize es'>8\staccato g bes4}
}
```

In case of chords, there is the special command `q` which repeats the last chord (it only repeat the pitches and it carries no information about duration, articulation, dynamics, etc):

```
\version "2.17.28"
{
  <a' c'' e''>4\p-> q q q |
  q-> q\ff q\p->\< q\! |
  d'8 e' q q q2 
}
```

You can also define shorter parts of the code and use them in the main code, such as:

```
\version "2.17.28"
A = {gis'8}
B = {<es \parenthesize es'>8\staccato g bes4}

{
  c2 \repeat unfold 8 {\A} r2 |
  es1 | \repeat unfold 2 {\B} | 
  \repeat unfold 16 {\A} |
  \repeat unfold 4 {\B}
}
```

---

As for your second question, I am also starting to learn to use functions on LilyPond. But well, it seems your code is equivalent to this code here, which is the most basic function (as far as I knew) in LilyPond:

```
\version "2.17.28"
S = #(define-event-function (parser location) ()
  #{ \staccato #}
)

P = #(define-event-function (parser location) ()
  #{ \parenthesize #}
)

{
es1 | <es \P es'>8\S g bes <es, \P es'>\S g bes 
}
```

So if you just want to substitute some long text into your code, you can use this template: `functionname = #(define-event-function (parser location) ()  #{ text #})`, where `functionname` and `text` have to be changed, but the rest should remain the same. Applied, it looks like this:

```
\version "2.17.28"
test = #(define-event-function (parser location) ()
  #{ ^"test"\fermata\trill->\pp #}
)
{c''1\test | d'' }
```

For something still a bit more complex, look at this example which is a `music-function` using `notes` as argument. Note how you can then manipulate where the arguments will be in the final output:

```
\version "2.17.28"
func = 
#(define-music-function
  (parser location notes)
  (ly:music?)
  #{ 
    % generates 2 low pitches with cross notehead
    \override Staff.NoteHead.style = #'cross
    g,8 a,

    % reverts back to the normal noteheads and uses the notes in the argument of the function
    \revert Staff.NoteHead.style
    $notes   % these will be substituted by the arguments when you call this function on your main code

    % generates 4 low pitches with cross notehead
    \override Staff.NoteHead.style = #'cross
    g,8 a, b, c
    % reverts back to the normal noteheads for the rest of the code
    \revert Staff.NoteHead.style
  #}
)

{
  \func { c''4 } | d''1
}
```

Now if you want to do something more complex, then you will need to really study the [documentation](http://grenouille.lilynet.net/lilypond-web/master/Documentation/extending/music-functions.zh.html) regarding music functions and try a lot by yourself. You can also check [this](http://grenouille.lilynet.net/lilypond-web/master/Documentation/extending/lilypond-code-blocks.zh.html) and [this](http://grenouille.lilynet.net/lilypond-web/master/Documentation/extending/scheme-function-definitions.zh.html) links out.

Comment: Thanks! After seeing this answer I've edited my question a bit for clarity.  Please note that (as I've just discovered) event functions are new in version 2.15.  I will try `define-music-function` then, and update with the results soon.

Comment: I've accepted this answer, and have posted a more specific follow-up question: [How to abbreviate 'note with the same note an octave higher, parenthesized' in Lilypond?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19464086/223837)

Comment: That `q` command is a fantastic hint, I had been searching for this and not finding it in the docs! Shouldn't it be mentioned in https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/repeats?