# How to abbreviate 'note with the same note an octave higher, parenthesized' in Lilypond?

Tags: scheme, guile, lilypond, music-notation

Currently I write [lilypond](/questions/tagged/lilypond) code that looks like this:

```
\version "2.14.2"

P = #parenthesize

\relative c, {
  \clef bass 
    <c \P c'> <e \P e'> <g \P g'>2 <c, \P c'>4 <d \P d'> <e \P e'>2
}
```

where I repeatedly mean '*this* note, together with the same note one octave higher, parenthesized'.

I'd like a way to abbreviate this, so that I can write something like this:

```
\version "2.14.2"

poct = ...

\relative c, {
  \clef bass 
  \poct c \poct e \poct g2 \poct c,4 \poct d \poct e2
}
```

As suggested in [a helpful answer to an earlier question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19412939/223837), I have tried to use [a music function](http://lilypond.org/doc/stable/Documentation/notation/using-music-functions), but there is no way I can get this to work.  The closest I can get is

```
poct = #(define-music-function
     (parser location note)
     (ly:music?)
   #{
     << $note \transpose c c \parenthesize $note >>
   #})
```

but this uses `<<` .. `>>` instead of `<` .. `>`, which does not render the way I want (and with warnings), and I have no idea why the `\transpose c c` actually transposes anything.

Finally, tangentially related, when experimenting with music functions I found it even impossible just to create a music function that mimicks `\repeat unfold 2`; the following jumps down an octave between the third and fourth `c`:

```
\version "2.14.2"

double = #(define-music-function
     (parser location note)
     (ly:music?)
   #{
     $note $note
   #})

\relative c, {
  \clef bass 
  \double c \double e \double g2 \double c,4 \double d \double e2
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  This _is_ a programming question, and the domain is the Lilypond/Scheme combo of languages.

Comment: That downvote was just ridiculous. This question is well researched, well written, full of tiny examples AND _LilyPond_ questions concerning programming (and not composing/notating music) DO belong here at _StackOverflow_.

Comment: And one more comment, regarding your question about `\transpose c c`. Well, on my version 2.17.28, it indeed does nothing (as I expected). But if you use `\transpose c c'`, then it will transpose everything one octave up (from c to c'). Try `\relative c' { a4 \transpose c c a r2 | a4 \transpose c c' a r2 }`, which should render firstly two identical notes a (not transposed because `\transpose c c` doesn't do anything) and then two other notes a, the second being one octave higher.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so here is a function I created for you, which will allow you to repeat single pitches. The only catch is that it won't use the `\relative` notation. This is because, in relative notation, the following sequence of notes `c' c' c'` will obviously be one octave higher than the preceding one. Unfortunately I still could not find a way to have a function such as `\function #3 c'` that would output `c' c c`. That said, here is my function and some examples:

```
\version "2.17.28"

times = #(define-music-function
     (parser location N note)
     (integer? ly:music?)
     (cond 
       ((>= N 2)
         #{ \repeat unfold $N { \absolute $note } #}
       )
       ((= N 1) 
         #{ \absolute $note #}
       )
     )
)

{
 a4 \times #3 b4
 R1
 \times #4 { c'8 d' }
 R1
 \times #1 { c''1 }
}
```

So the syntax is simply `\times #"number of repetition" { ...music... }`. If only one note is to be repeated, you can omit both `{` and `}`: `\times #"number of repetition" "single note"`.

You can use this function in the middle of a `\relative` passage, but then you should enter the pitches for the function as absolute pitches. Have a look:

```
\version "2.17.28"

times = #(define-music-function
     (parser location N note)
     (integer? ly:music?)
     (cond 
       ((>= N 2)
         #{ \repeat unfold $N { \absolute $note } #}
       )
       ((= N 1) 
         #{ \absolute $note #}
       )
     )
)

\relative c'' {
  c4 d \times #4 e'' f g
}
```

Note that all notes above are in the same octave. The octave position the note `f` is also NOT influenced by this function, it is influenced by the note preceding the function, i.e., the `d`.

For sure there is a way to write a better code for this, but I wasn't able to do the trick with neither any `\relative` nor `\transpose` commands.

---

And here is some attempt to help you with your parenthesized octave (same function above but with some small alterations):

```
\version "2.17.28"

timesP = #(define-music-function
     (parser location N note)
     (integer? ly:music?)
     (cond 
       ((>= N 2)
         #{ 
           << 
             \repeat unfold $N { \absolute $note } 
             \transpose c c' \repeat unfold $N { \absolute \parenthesize $note } 
           >>
         #}
       )
       ((= N 1) 
         #{ 
           << 
             \absolute $note 
             { \transpose c c' \parenthesize $note }
           >>
         #}
       )
     )
)

{
 a4 \timesP #3 b4
 \timesP #8 c'16
 \timesP #2 g4
 \timesP #4 { c'8 d' } % no parenthesis here because there are two notes as arguments...
 \timesP #1 { c''1 } % no parenthesis here because of the { }
}

\relative c'' {
  c4 d \timesP #4 e'' f g
}
```

There are still some catches here: this function will only parenthesize when the argument is a single note written without `{ }`. This is well commented on the code above.

---

I hope this will help you somehow. If I come across the solution for the octave transposition problem here, I will update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this answer from David Kastrup, one of the developers of LilyPond:

---

The "octave transposition" happens because basically \transpose c c is the same as \absolute (as LilyPond does not apply \relative to transposed music).

\absolute is not necessary in connection with \repeat unfold: \repeat unfold knows how to deal with relative music.

Version 2.14.2 is awfully old.  At any rate, there is currently issue http://code.google.com/p/lilypond/issues/detail?id=3673 in the LilyPond tracker, and the respective code can be found at https://codereview.appspot.com/30890043/diff/40001/scm/music-functions.scm

And there we get indeed into Scheme programming.  The respective defmacro-public would likely work even in 2.14 though #{ #} might not work properly.

With that definition, your double definition would become:

double = #(define-music-function
     (parser location note)
     (ly:music?)
  (make-relative (note) note
   #{
     $note $note
   #}))

and would then work in both absolute and relative mode.  If the 2.14 #{ #} does not jibe with make-relative, writing (make-sequential-music (list (ly:music-deep-copy note) (ly:music-deep-copy note))) should serve as a Scheme replacement.

The original problem becomes easier to understand once you realize that it's just a simple code replacement, so \relative { \double c' } becomes \relative { c' c' } using different octaves.  The make-relative macro will to the \relative operation only on a single note, and then paste the results into the music expression.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in your question and the answer from David Kastrup quoted in another reply, I built the following code to turn notes into chords with the same note one octave higher, *not* parenthesized:

```
#(define (octavate-pitch pitch octaves)
   (ly:make-pitch
    (+ (ly:pitch-octave pitch) octaves)
    (ly:pitch-notename pitch)
    (ly:pitch-alteration pitch)))

#(define (articulation-is-of-type? art type)
   (string=? (ly:music-property art 'articulation-type) type))

#(define (copy-articulation? art)
   (cond ((music-is-of-type? art 'tie-event)
          #t)
         ((and (music-is-of-type? art 'articulation-event)
               (articulation-is-of-type? art "fermata"))
          #f)
         ; TODO add more cases
         (else
          #f)))

#(define (octNote note)
   (if (null? (ly:music-property note 'pitch))
       note
       (make-relative (note) note
                      (let ((note2 (ly:music-deep-copy note))
                            (pitch (ly:music-property note 'pitch)))
                        (set! (ly:music-property note2 'pitch)
                              (octavate-pitch pitch 1))
                        (set! (ly:music-property note2 'articulations)
                              (filter copy-articulation? (ly:music-property note2 'articulations)))
                        (make-event-chord (list note note2))))))

oct = #(define-music-function
           (parser location music)
           (ly:music?)
         (music-map octNote music))
```

It can be applied to an individual note or a full music expression:

```
\relative c' \oct {
  c d e f |
  g2 g |
}
```

It also works in the opposite order, `\oct \relative c' { … }`.

To parenthesize the added note, replace the last reference to `note2` in `octNote` with `(parenthesize note2)` – I just prefer the non-parenthesized version for my own use. (You should probably rename the functions to `octPNote` and `octP` in that case, to avoid confusion. I briefly tried to write `octPNote` as a function that calls `octNote` and post-processes the result to parenthesize the second note, but wasn’t successful.)

You will also almost certainly need to expand the `copy-articulation?` predicate – ties and fermate are just the two kinds of articulation I encountered. (It defaults to not copying unknown articulations, so if the predicate is incomplete you’ll see it as missing articulations on the copied note.)